# What is the cause of the weird output in the plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, rendering, opacity

**Bug fixed in 12.3**

---

I am using v12.1.
I printed out the graph using the plot as follows.
But there was a strange dirt. This phenomenon occurs in the Sin and Cos functions.

```
Plot[Sin[3 x], {x, -6, 6}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.05], Opacity[0.5]}]
```

[image]

I tried to run this on Wolfram Player 12.3. The first open state looks the same. However, if you click with a mouse, the dirt on the graph disappears.

The following is the video address for the strange phenomenon I explained.

https://youtu.be/yKldQlLxT_U

What is the cause of the weird output in the plot?

Comment: The curves are being chopped up into sub-splines / lines and the end caps don't join up. It seems to be fixed in v13.0 on Windows - somebody should also try it out on 12.3.1.

Comment: if you do not have  to use `Opacity` you can also try  `PlotStyle -> {Lighter@Lighter@Red, JoinForm["Round"],   CapForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05]}`

Comment: I do not reproduce the problem with versions 12.3.1 and 13.0.0 on Windows 10 x64. So the bug seems to be fixed in version 12.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a consequence of the adaptive plotting routines. On v. 12.0 (Win10-64) you can prevent that at the cost of the convenient adaptive features of Plot by preventing recursive adjustments to the number of points used in plotting:

```
Plot[
 Sin[3 x], {x, -6, 6},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.05], Opacity[0.3]],
 PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 0
]
```

[image: same plot, no artifacts]

Comment: The adaptive sampling in Plot is only related, in that it tends to increase the number of points used, and you're more likely to see this as the number of points in the curve increases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are performance issues drawing lines with large number of points that can vary by operating system.  In order to mitigate these, long lines may get split into smaller chunks.  If the line is thin or opaque, you generally don't notice.  When the line is thick and transparent, you can get artifacts as a result.

Let's parametrize a spiral so that we can control how many points are used to draw it:

```
In[122]:= spiral[n_] := Table[{t Cos[t], t Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi, 6 Pi/(n - 1)}]

In[123]:= Length[spiral[10]]

Out[123]= 10
```

On my machine, the line splitting happens every 100 points, and you start to see overlaps from the default `CapForm`:

```
base = Directive[AbsoluteThickness[20], Red, Opacity[0.33]];

Table[Graphics[{base, Line[spiral[n]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> n], {n, {100, 101, 1000}}]
```

[image]

If you set `CapForm[None]`, the overlap artifacts *mostly* disappear, but you can now sometimes get "gap" artifacts:

```
Table[Graphics[{base, CapForm[None], Line[spiral[n]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> n], {n, {100, 101, 1000}}]
```

[image]
If you set `CapForm["Round"]`, you can get an interesting effect:

```
Table[Graphics[{base, CapForm["Round"], Line[spiral[n]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> n], {n, {100, 101, 1000}}]
```

[image]
In general these behaviors may vary between versions and across operating systems.

Comment: So, is this a bug or "expected behaviour"?

Comment: It's expected, but not necessarily desirable.  But neither are some of the alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

Version 12.2.0 Win7x64; The following could be version dependent so please consider it an extended comment.

---

With `MaxRecursion->0`, and for exploring the comment by Brett Champion;

```
Plot[Sin[2 x], {x, -4, 4}
 , PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]
   , Opacity[0.5]}
 ,  Mesh -> All
 , PlotPoints -> {1000, 501}
 , ImageSize -> Large
 , MaxRecursion -> 0
 ]
```

The first argument to `PlotPoints` is (?) ignored. You can increase it to 100000 if you want.

For the second argument **501** is the number for `Sin` `Cos` plots where the square artifacts appear, but it doesn't hold for `Tan` plot. The `Tan` plot seems to be the best behaved one (even with MaxRecursion on). Someone with a developer's knowledge of the algorithm could say more.

Further I tried:

`Plot[x^2, {x, -4, 4}` ... (x^n same trend)

and the magic number (yet again) is 501 where the square artifacts first appear. For Cosh, Sinh etc the number is slightly higher at around 620.